# Update label location in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, runtime

I have a method that returns a value, and I want this value to be the new location of a label in a windows form application.  but I'm being told that a label's location is not a variable.  objectA is the name of the label.

```
objectA.Location.X = (int)A.position;
objectA.Refresh();
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `Left` property to change X coordinate of a `Label`

```
objectA.Left = 100;
```

Comment: In the end, both the Left property and the Location property use the SetBounds method internally. The advantage with the Left property is that you don't have to create a new Point object witch might be a bit faster if you do it intensely...

Answer (score 22):

the Location property is of type Point, which is a value type. Therefore, the property returns a copy of the location value, so setting X on this copy would have no effect on the label. The compiler sees that and generates an error so that you can fix it. You can do that instead :

```
objectA.Location = new Point((int)A.position, objectA.Location.Y);
```

(the call to Refresh is useless)

Answer (score 12):

This works to me

```
this.label1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
```

You even do not need to call Refresh or SuspendLayout etc.

so this should help you

```
this.label1.Location = new Point((int)A.position, (int)A.otherpos);
```

Answer (score 1):

> objectname.Location =
>   System.Drawing.Point(100,100);

Answer (score 0):

```
objectA.Location = new Point((int)A.position, objectA.Location.Y);
objectA.Refresh();
```

Location is no a variable, just a public Property.
Changing variables through properties is a bady idea unless you have events that update the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set properties of structs if you have a direct reference to that struct:

```
Point loc = objectA.Location;
loc.X = (int)A.position;
objectA.Location = loc;
```