# Non-invocable member

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update label location in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968728/update-label-location-in-c)

I am creating a custom windows form and when trying to change the location of the label I get the error:Error   1   Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' cannot be used like a method.  C:\Users\Ran\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SyncCustomForm\SyncCustomForm\SyncControl1.cs    50  24  SyncCustomForm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SyncCustomForm
{
    public partial class SyncControl : UserControl
    {

        public SyncControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ProgressBar prbSyncProgress
        {
            get { return prbProgress; }
        }
        public Label lblException
        {
            get { return lblMessage; }
        }
        public Label lblStatus
        {
            get { return lblS; }
        }
        public Button btnPause
        {
            get { return btnP; }
        }
        public Button btnStop
        {
            get { return btnS; }
        }
        public GroupBox grbxSync
        {
            get { return gbxSync; }
        }

        private void SyncControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lblMessage.Location.X = 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you exposing all your private parts?  Just like in real life, this is strongly discouraged in programming too...  (I'm referring to your public Label, Button, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Location` property is a struct and `X` is a property of that structure, and in this case you cannot set the value of `X` independently.

You need to do this:

```
lblMessage.Location = new Point(50, 50); // both X and Y will be set this way
```

or if you want to set only X value, set the Left property:

```
lblMessage.Left = 50;
```

You can only set properties of structs if you have a direct reference to that struct:

```
var loc = lblMessage.Location;
loc.X = 50;
lblMessage.Location = loc;
```