# c# change Label (Control) location at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, location, label

The default tooltip isn't working well for me, so I made a custom tooltip using a Label Control and its 'Visible' property as an error Popup when a key is pressed. So now **I'm trying to set the position of the label dynamically, in my case to the location of a textBox, but it always shows up in the upper left corner of the form.**

Here's the method:

```
    void ShowCustomToolTip(string text, Control targetControl, int duration = 1000, int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        customToolTip.Text = text;
        customToolTip.Visible = true;

        // the crucial line that needs to be changed, I guess
        customToolTip.Location = new Point(targetControl.Location.X + x, targetControl.Location.Y + y);

        Set.Timer(duration);
        customToolTip.Hide();
    }
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that `targetControl.Location` is the location of the control inside it's container (i.e. not relative to the window)?

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, it's the location of a control inside the main form, where I want the label to appear.

Comment: I'm saying, does the `targetControl` exist inside another control like a tab view or a panel? The `Location` property is always relative to it's container, NOT the form.

Comment: Oh well, it exists inside a split container. How would I go about setting the location of the label then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update label location in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968728/update-label-location-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`Control.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx) gives your position within the current container. You just need to get the absolute location of the control with respect to the form like this:

```
void ShowCustomToolTip(string text, Control targetControl, int duration = 1000, int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
    customToolTip.Text = text;
    customToolTip.Visible = true;

    Point absoluteLocation = targetControl.FindForm().PointToClient(
        targetcontrol.Parent.PointToScreen(control.Location));

    // the crucial line that needs to be changed, I guess
    customToolTip.Location = new Point(absoluteLocation.X + x, absoluteLocation.Y + y);

    Set.Timer(duration);
    customToolTip.Hide();
}
```